# Xcode 4.2 Portrait and Landscape and Alignment

Tags: iphone, xcode

Xcode 4.2

I am using UIWebView to display two pictures side by side. In Portrait they align left with a big space on the right of the two pictures rather than align center, and it looks odd.

Is there a way to have them align center?

also related,

How do I turn the display to Landscape in the Nib file in Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the orientation to Landscape in the Attribute Insperctor to turn the display to Landscape. And you can use Autosizing in the Size Inspector to align the images on center.

Comment: I found them. Thanks for the direction. Is there a way to force Landscape when the User gets to the screen without the User having to turn the phone to initiate Landscape?

Comment: yes. You can use  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateInterfaceOrientation :(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation method for this

Answer (score 0):

To turn on your display to the landscape use this method.This will set your orientation to landscape mode.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
```